# javascript countdown lagging because of ajax calls

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, curl

I use a javascript song countdown on my radio website.

At every 10 seconds, the countdown lags (skipping 1 one more seconds), because of an ajax call to check if there's a new song:

```
function getcursong(){  
  var result = null;
  var scriptUrl = "get_current_song.php";
  $.ajax({
    url: scriptUrl,
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'html',
    async: false,
    success: function(data) {
        result = data;
    } 
  });
  return result;
}
```

Looking in the console, I see that the `GET` call takes about 2 seconds.

`get_current_song.php` uses `curl` to get the current song from the icecast server.

Is there something I can do to prevent the countdown from lagging because of those ajax calls?

Below is `get_current_song.php`.

```
<?php 
require('config.php');
$current_song = getStreamInfo();
function url_get_contents($Url) {
    if (!function_exists('curl_init')){ 
        die('CURL is not installed!');
    }
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $Url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,2);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $output;
}
function getStreamInfo(){
    $str = url_get_contents(SERVER.'/status.xsl?mount='.MOUNT);
    if(preg_match_all('/<td\s[^>]*class=\"streamdata\">(.*)<\/td>/isU', $str, $match)){
        $x = explode(" * ",$match[1][9]); 
        return $x[1];
    }
}
?>
<?php
    echo $current_song;
?>
```

Comment: Don't make the ASYNCHRONOUS call synchron ;)

Comment: @Jeffman is correct.  Remove the `async: false` (default is an implicit `async: true`) if you don't need it to be.

Comment: It's not working with async = true.

Comment: Because after I do : gcs = getcursong();     gcs is null because async=true.  What can I do ?

Comment: ok I found out : function ()
{
     var result = null;
     var scriptUrl = "get_current_song.php";
     $.ajax({
        url: scriptUrl,
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'html',
        async: true,
        success: function(data) {
            song = $('#song').html();
            if (data != song && data != ""){
                setTimeout(function (){ $('#nowplaying').load('nowplaying.php'); }, 5000); // pourquoi fadeIn("slow"); ?!?
            }            
        } 
     }); 
}, 10000);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that `async: false` is hijacking your countdown function. Do you need it to be false?

Comment: Wow! I see. No more lagging now. Thanks for the fast reply.

Answer (score 0):

```
function ()
{
 var result = null;
 var scriptUrl = "get_current_song.php";
 $.ajax({
    url: scriptUrl,
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'html',
    async: true,  // NEEDED TO BE TRUE
    success: function(data) {     // on success, I get the data
        song = $('#song').html();
        if (data != song && data != ""){
            setTimeout(function (){ $('#nowplaying').load('nowplaying.php'); }, 5000); // pourquoi fadeIn("slow"); ?!?
        }            
    } 
 }); 
}, 10000);
```